# Meaning of equations associated with Legendre transform

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, crystals, semiclassical

In the famous paper about semiclassical Bloch theory https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9511014, the Lagrangian
\begin{eqnarray}
L (\mathbf{k},\dot{\mathbf{k}}) = -e \delta \mathbf{A}(r,t)\cdot\dot{\mathbf{r}} -\hbar \mathbf{k}\cdot\dot{\mathbf{r}}  + \hbar \dot{\mathbf{k}} \cdot \mathcal{A}(\mathbf{k}) - E(\mathbf{k}), \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}
leads to Euler-Lagrange equations,
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{\mathbf{r}} = \frac{1}{\hbar}\frac{\partial E(\mathbf{k})}{\partial \mathbf{k}} - \dot{\mathbf{k}} \times \Omega_n(\mathbf{k}), \ \ \ \ \ \\ 
\hbar \dot{\mathbf{k}} = -e\mathbf{E} -e \dot{\mathbf{r}} \times \delta \mathbf{B}. \tag{2} \end{eqnarray}
which are massively popular in literature.

Then, with a Legendre transform, the following Hamiltonian with a conjugate momentum $\mathbf{\pi}$ is found,
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{\pi} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{\mathbf{k}}} L = -\frac{\hbar}{2} l_B'^2  \mathbf{k} \times \hat{z} + \hbar  \mathcal{A} \tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
H(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{\pi}) = \mathbf{\pi}\cdot\dot{\mathbf{k}} - L(\mathbf{k}.\dot{\mathbf{k}}) = E(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{\pi})   \tag{4}
\end{eqnarray}

Now, from the discussion on Legendre transform in https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Variational_Principles_in_Classical_Mechanics_(Cline)/08%3A_Hamiltonian_Mechanics/8.02%3A_Legendre_Transformation_between_Lagrangian_and_Hamiltonian_mechanics, the eq.s 8.2.9 and 8.2.10 are ``strictly a result of the Legendre transformation'':

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}L(\mathbf{q},\dot{\mathbf{q}},t) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}H(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q},t) \tag{8.2.9}
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}L(\mathbf{q},\dot{\mathbf{q}},t) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t}H(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q},t)  \tag{8.2.10}
\end{eqnarray}
I want to understand if (8.2.9), (8.2.10) give rise to equations of motion that are different than the Euler-Lagrange equations in eq. (2). If they are indeed different, then what do these new equations mean? Do the Hamilton's equations describe a different dynamics?

In the derivation of Euler-Lagrange equation (eq. (2)), the following derivative is evaluated to be,
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{k}}L(\mathbf{k},\dot{\mathbf{k}},t) = -\hbar \dot{\mathbf{r}} + \hbar \dot{\mathbf{k}} \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{k}}\mathcal{A}(\mathbf{k}) -\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{k}}E(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{\pi},t) \tag{5}
\end{eqnarray}
which is different from the equation that would de derived using (8.2.9)
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{k}}L(\mathbf{k},\dot{\mathbf{k}},t) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{k}}E(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{\pi},t) \tag{8.2.9a}
\end{eqnarray}

What do these ``strictly a result of the Legendre transformation'' equation (8.2.9) and (8.2.10) mean? Like with these extra equations, you can derive new relationships e.g. from eq.s (5) and (8.2.9a),
\begin{eqnarray}
-\hbar \dot{\mathbf{r}} + \hbar \dot{\mathbf{k}} \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{k}}\mathcal{A}(\mathbf{k})=0 \tag{6}
\end{eqnarray}
These new equations like eq. (6) seem like a new equation of motion (in addition to eq. 2). What do they mean? Are they an artifact of Legendre Transform only?

Comment: Just to add some caution, it is usually the case that we start from position and velocity, configuration space, in the Lagrangian $q,\ \dot q$ and the Legendre transform converts to position and momentum, phase space, in the Hamiltonian $q,\ p$. The equation of motion should not differ. Here, $k$ is really a momentum, $\dot k$ is the time derivative of momentum, which is convertible back to position, here $r$. The paper is thus in a complicated situation, and it might take a while to decipher what things mean.